# Remove dataframe rows if index larger than x

Tags: python, pandas

I want to remove dataframe rows that index is larger than 13491.

I tried

```
df.drop(df.index > [13491])
```

but received error

```
KeyError: 'labels [False False False ...  True  True  True] not contained in axis'
```

This one works fine

```
df= df[df.index < 13492]
```

But how to remove the filtered rows from dataframe ?

Can someone give me some suggestions ? Thank you in advanced !

Comment: Your proposed solution should work. Have you checked it?

Comment: @Alessandro thank you, the question is a silly mistake haha

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
df= df[df.index < 13492]
```

works for this case

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use drop, you could identify the row with the help of [numpy.where()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame()

df["A"] = [1,2,3,4,5]
   A
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4

#Remove if index bigger thans 2
df.drop(df.index[np.where(df.index > 2)[0]])
   A
0  1
1  2
2  3
```

But your method of giving back `df = df[df.index < some_value]` should not be bad either. Keep in mind that drop will return a changed object and not overwrite the old one. so a `df = df.drop ...` is needed to replace df either way.